# How to define transitive CXX_STANDARD C++11 in Cmake

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I have a header only C++11 library, so I want to configure it, using CMake > 3.1, compile features seems reasonable way to do so:

```
target_compile_features(my_header_lib INTERFACE cxx_range_for)
```

But I would prefer not having to indicate individual features, but just C++11 or C++14. Then I could try to use the following:

```
set_property(TARGET my_target PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

The problem is that my_target cannot be INTERFACE here, it is not supported, and I cannot define it PUBLIC, so consumers (many EXEs) of my header only library will automatically have the C++11 configuration propagated from the lib.

Is there some way to define at a high level 11/14 standard, but also configure it for a header only (INTERFACE) library? I would prefer not to fall back to old manual -std=c++11.

Comment: Indeed, it is a deliberate design choice not to support a `INTERFACE_CXX_STANDARD` target property. See also the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[CMake 3.8](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/release/3.8.html) (released in April 2017) introduced meta-features (e.g. **cxx_std_11**, **cxx_std_14**, **cxx_std_17**). You can now for instance write:

```
target_compile_features(my_header_lib INTERFACE cxx_std_11)
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution for now is to manually maintain lists of C++11 and C++14 features in a global variable and feed that list to `target_compile_features`.

```
set(CXX11_FEATURES
    cxx_auto_type
    cxx_constexpr
    [...]
)

set(CXX14_FEATURES
    cxx_generic_lambdas
    [...]
)

target_compile_features(my_header_lib INTERFACE ${CXX11_FEATURES} ${CXX14_FEATURES})
```

Arguably, it would be nice if CMake already provided those lists for you, but currently it does not.

Note that this is consistent with how the compile features mechanism currently works in CMake. The `CXX_STANDARD` property determines which flag is given to the compiler on the command line. Just because you request a certain standard version however does not guarantee that it will correctly compile a certain feature. The only way to ensure that a certain feature is present (and fail with a meaningful error if it's not) is by checking it through `target_compile_features`.

The complication here really is not due to how CMake handles things, but due to the fact that different compilers implement different subsets of the standard.

Comment: Yes, that is a good approach I think. And yes, I think it would be a good idea that CMake define the lists for us. There is a little problem yet, is that target_compile_features seems to be not fully data-implemented for compilers as MinGW, and I am getting some errors, despite it seems solved in https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15443. Will try this and post another question if necessary.

Comment: @drodri Yes, `target_compile_features` is not very reliable right now. IIRC it only works with recent versions gcc and clang at the moment. I hope this will be resolved soon, because in general it's a very cool feature of CMake.

Comment: The list of features known to the compiler are in http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/variable/CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES.html#variable:CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES . GCC 4.4 is the oldest GCC release supported, Clang version shipped with Xcode 4.0, and MSVC 2010. Those are old. It's not true to say only recent compilers are supported.

Comment: @steveire Good to hear. Just looked it up and last time I tried was with 3.1. Back then I could not get it to work properly with MSVC, so I'm glad to hear this is fixed by now. And yeah, checking for CXX11 support in compilers older than the ones you mentioned is probably not very useful to begin with.

Comment: The supported compilers as of 3.2 have been documented in master: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#supported-compilers